# Apply jquery plugin dotdotdot on angularjs repeat with pagination

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to setup a directive to apply the jquery plugin [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).  My issue is that I want it to apply to a list of items in ng-repeat with pagination set.  The list will chang with each next/prev page click.  I can not get even the initial page to work with code below.

Here is my code so far:

```
videoApp.directive('myEllip', function() {
var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var synopsis = angular.element(element.children());
    $(synopsis).dotdotdot({'watch':true});
};
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFn
};
});


 <ul class="videos_all" my-ellip >
 <li ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:search | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize " class="videoSynopsis" >
      <p><a href ng-click="showVideo('{{video.VideoID}}')" >
      {{video.Title}}</a>
      <br><small class="muted">{{video.Description}}</small></p>        
</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting an

> dotdotdot: No element found for "".

in the console.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem but I had a directive for each element in the list and when I called `dotdotdot()` it would stop angular from binding my `{{title}}` to the value so I switched to `ng-bind="title"` instead and it worked.
I suppose in your case it could look something like:

```
videoApp.directive('myEllip', function() {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.dotdotdot({'watch':true});
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

and html

```
<ul class="videos_all">
  <li my-ellip ng-repeat="video in videos | filter:search | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize " class="videoSynopsis" >
    <p>
      <a href ng-click="showVideo('{{video.VideoID}}')" ng-bind="video.Title"></a>
      <br/>
      <small class="muted" ng-bind="video.Description"></small>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how `dotdotdot` works for child elements so you might also need some css on those `a` and `small` for it to work (which I assume you have already).

Comment: please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197197/angularjs-dotdotdot-for-overflow-text-and-performance?noredirect=1#28197197

Answer (score 0):

**Template**

```
<div dma-dotdotdot>{{movie.title}}</div>
```

**Directive**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dma.common').directive('dmaDotDotDot', [
        function dmaDotDotDot() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                        element.dotdotdot({
                            wrap: 'letter'
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
}());
```

I tested ng-bind and it doesn't seem to work properly for me. ng-bind hides the content, then fires the dotdotdot(), then compiles the content (Which doesn't work).

Though this should work—Much better solution than scope.$watch. And I believe it preforms more consistently than the solutions listed without `$evalAsync()`.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync for more information regarding when it fires.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax error.

Change  `<ul class="videos_all" my-ellip >`
to `<ul class="videos_all" myEllip >`

Edit:

```
<input ng-model="test" type="text" value="23"/>
<div  ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px" dotdotdot ng-bind="test"></div>
</div>

app.directive('dotdotdot', function() {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).dotdotdot({'watch':true});
    }
})
```

Comment: Not a syntax error.  I should add that I am using Angular 1.2 rc3.  THe syntax is correct.  Angular changes the camelback notation to hyphenated for attributes.